# Minify multi-document yaml

Tags: yaml

I have a multi-document yaml such as this (very simplified) example:

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
a: b
y: z
---
c: d
x:
  - 1
  - e
```

I am trying to minimize it, but all the online tools I found for minimizing YAML (e.g. https://onlineyamltools.com/minify-yaml, etc.) don't work for multi-document yaml files. Is it possible to use inline yaml syntax (i.e "minified yaml") with multi-document?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (not to be confused with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) of the same name) with its [`style`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/style) operator to set everything `..` to `flow`:

```bash
yq '.. style="flow"' input.yaml
```

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
{a: b, y: z}
---
{c: d, x: [1, e]}
```